# TFS 2015 - How do you export security for a collection / project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

In Team Foundation Server 2015, Is there a way to export the security setup, TFS Groups, Windows Groups, by collection, etc?

There is a lot of security setup in TFS 2015 and it doesn't come over when upgrading to Azure DevOps 2020.0.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Thanks @VitoLiu-MSFT, I've struggled to get the script to work, and also to have time to work on it.  I've not used tfssecurity utility before, so there is a bit of learning curve.   Should I use the script just as you have it, just replace the collectionURL and ServerURL?

For example should this sample code work? [/collection:HTTP://tfsServer:8080/tfsCollection] and [/server:HTTP://tfsServer:8080/tfs]

Comment: Hi @JM1, these should all work, such as Display available namespaces `tfssecurity /a /server:HTTP://tfsServer:8080/tfsCollection` and Display available actions `tfssecurity /a Server /collection:HTTP://tfsServer:8080/tfsCollection`

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?